# Why is my Back Reference in my Regular Expression Not Working?

Tags: regex, backreference

I wrote a regular expression trying to match some html code but I can't quite it to work. I'm having a problem with the part after "wp-caption".

```
class=(["\'])(?:[\w\s])*?wp-caption[\s\1]
```

The code I want to match:

```
class="wp-caption"
class='wp-caption'
class="wp-caption foo"
class="foo wp-caption"
```

I match the first three results but not the fourth. I don't think the \1 is working. Any thoughts?

BTdubs I've been using http://regexpal.com/ for testing purposes.

Comment: I've never seen "BTdubs" before. That's delightful.

Comment: You're right, back references doesn't works inside brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
class=(["\'])(?:[\w\s])*wp-caption[\w\s]*\1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work too

```
class\s*=\s*(['"])(?:(?!\1).)*wp-caption(?:(?!\1).)*\1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because backreferences can't be referenced from within a character class (the stuff inside the square brackets `[]`). As mentioned in another answer, you could use a backrefence in a lookahead, unless you're using a language that doesn't support lookaround...

In short, what you need to do depends upon the language you are using (regex implementations depend heavily on what language is implementing them)

Comment: I haven't even heard about lookaheads. So why does the backreference work with the first three examples?

Comment: @BFTrick honestly, I'm not sure why it would work with the first two - I'm fairly proficient in several flavors of regex (including JavaScript, which I am assuming you are using) and I don't see how your expression could match the first two lines, but I cut and pasted your example expression and code into regexpal.com just to be sure, and it only matches the third line in your example...

Comment: @BFTrick `[\s\1]` means essentially "match either a whitespace character (space, tab, CrLf, and others), a backslash, _or_ a literal digit `1`" - if you were trying to identify any class attribute that _contained_ `wp-caption`, then I assume you removed some other classes that were _following_ `wp-caption` and matches were only successful because the they hit on the whitespace between those classes - they _should not be able_ to match the first two lines in your example code using your expression. [-->More info on 'lookaround'](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)